# Secure ways to implement CSRF free JWT authentification

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, csrf, jwt

I have just learned about JWT for authentification. Storing the JWT token in localStorage/sessionStorage is exposed to XSS. Storing it in a cookie is vulnerable to CSRF. I have been researching this and I thought of this solution, but I'm not sure how secure is this and if I should be using it in production.

The soulution is to get the JWT token from server, store it in cookie. Generate a CSRF token (that will be stored in JWT) that will be sent with each HTML page, either in a hidden HTML field of as a global JS variable (). That CSRF token will be sent with every request using JS/AJAX. This way we can rule out CSRF first then verify the JWT token.

I'm not sure whether a new token should be sent with each loaded page, or a single token should be held per session. The 1st case would mean that only the last loaded page/form would be able to submit (which could be problematic if the user is having multiple tabs of other pages open).

**Is this a secure solution that might be used in production ?**

**Also, what other solutions would be viable to reach the same goal ?**

Comment: JWT related to API authentication, I think no need for CSRF since you authenticate your request with JWT already,  or you can block cross origin request and limit it to certain domains

Comment: I don't think you read my post, but anyways, See here why CSRF protection is needed when storing authentification token in cookies https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my understanding of the issue.

- JWT Token - stored in httponly/secure cookie - this ensures any Javascript does not have access to it
- CSRF Token - stored by JS - on login, attach the claims as a header (including your CSRF value)

When the JS gets the header, it can store the claim in a cookie, localstorage, or session storage.  Because no JS has access to the JWT token in the cookie, by attaching the CSRF with every request and making sure it matches what's in the JWT, you're ensuring that it's your JS sending the request and that it was your backend that issued the token.

A hidden field isn't a great solution because you'll have to add it to each request.  Depending on what framework you're using, you should be able to load the CSRF token into whatever is responsible for sending the token as a header on each request when the page is refreshed.  The benefit to having all the claims in local storage or a cookie is you can preserve the users front end state.  Having the exp claim means you can tell when the user no longer has a valid token in the secure jwt token cookie and you can redirect to a login page.

- sessionstorage - is specific to the tab only
- localstorage - is specific to the domain across tabs
- cookie - is specific to the domain across tabs

Add CSFR to AJAX request:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("CSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken);
        },
        url: "entities",
        data: "json=" + escape(JSON.stringify(createRequestObject)),
        processData: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#results").append("The result =" + StringifyPretty(msg));
        }
});
```

Even though you're not using Angular, this still applies.  You should attach the token as a header with the JS and it's fine to get that value from a cookie.

From the [Angular JS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> When performing XHR requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN). Since only JavaScript that runs on your domain can read the cookie, your server can be assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your domain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A few points you misunderstood though :

"CSRF Token - stored by JS", It wouldn't be stored by JS. It will be sent by the server within each HTML page, either as a hidden field or as a global JS variable (`echo '<script>var xsrf = \'' . $token . '\';</script>';`

Also, I'm not using anything other than jQuery/JS client-side and PHP server-side. My understanding was to sendback the csrf token in a regular POST variable, using AJAX. How can I send that in a header ?

Comment: If you put the CSRF in a cookie, you don't have to add it to every request to make it available to the PHP, it will be included automatically.  If you don't want to use a cookie, you can add a header to the AJAX request - see edited post.

Comment: Thank you for the header solution. But doesn't storing the CSRF token in a cookie actually defy the purpose of the CSRF token ?

Comment: You're correct, you should not just trust the cookie.  The Javascript can take the value from the cookie but needs to attach it as a header.  See my edit.